# Bootstrap popover click event code is not run every time popover is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, jquery-events

I have a function that if certain conditions are met [via input from 3 different fields (two `<input>` elements and one `<selection>` element] will create and display a popover on the  element. I am currently displaying the popover ONLY when all 3 fields have values in them so I can test the show/hide functionality of the popover.  The selection element is tied to the popover...

```
<select data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" class="invalid-model-popover        select-group aircraft-model" style="width: 90%;">
    <option value="default" selected>Select a model...</option>
</select>
```

This is the code I'm using to create the popover.

```
verifyRoute: function() {

    $('#' + this.currentLeg.attr('id') + ' .invalid-model-popover').popover({
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: "<div style='display:inline-block;width:100%'><i class='glyphicon         glyphicon-remove pull-right'>" +
                "</i></div>" +
                "<div style='font-weight:bold'>Note:</div>" +
                "<div>Aircraft range does not meet<br>leg requirements." +
                "Select<br>alternate aircraft or arrange<br>fuel" +
                " stops</div>"

    }).click(function(event) {   
            $('#' + routeVerifier.currentLeg.attr('id') + ' .glyphicon-remove').click(function() {
            $('#' + routeVerifier.currentLeg.attr('id') + ' .invalid-model-popover').popover('hide');
        });

    });

    $('#' + this.currentLeg.attr('id') + " .invalid-model-popover").popover('show');
},
```

So currently when I generate the popover from the set of actions, "Enter something in BOTH text inputs, select an option from the select element, popover appears, and hit "x" then" the popover closes. When I use the sequence "select an option from the select element, enter something in both text inputs" then the popover appears but the onClick of the "x" is not set up. If I step through the code the code to register the event....

```
.click(function(event) {   
        $('#' + routeVerifier.currentLeg.attr('id') + ' .glyphicon-remove').click(function() {
        $('#' + routeVerifier.currentLeg.attr('id') + ' .invalid-model-popover').popover('hide');
    });

});
```

is not even run. Here is a fiddle to illustrate the issue http://jsfiddle.net/restin84/fxf9wneb/68/ Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Here it is @Innodel [http://jsfiddle.net/restin84/fxf9wneb/68/]. You can use the same scenarios above and get the same described results. The text boxes trigger popover creation on the onBlur event so just click out of them.

Comment: i think in current fiddle, the popover comes when there is something in two inputs and select tag. But now clarify me what exactly you want instead.

Comment: Yes I want the popover to appear when all three elements have something in them. This is the problem: Fill in both text inputs, select an option from the drop down --> click listener for "x" on popover works. Select an option from the dropdown, fill in both text inputs --> click listener for "x" on popover DOES NOT work. What I want is the "close on click of the X" to work no matter what order I select/fill in the elements

Comment: But it is already there in that fiddle, When you select "option 2" or "option 3" from select tag and also having something in input box than popup is coming, than what's your problem?

Comment: I cannot close the popover by clicking the "x" (on the popover) depending on which order I place values in the inputs. Please read my last comment. The problem is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fxf9wneb/72/

Problem is actually occurs because when you are binding click event of 'X' button, it was actually not there on HTML document. So '.glyphicon-remove' selector has length 0. I have just added popover shown event to your code and i have binded click event of 'X' button when popover is shown to user. and it is working like a charm.

```js
var verifier = {
    inputOne: null,
    inputTwo: null,
    selection: null,

    init: function () {
        this.inputOne = $('#input-1');
        this.inputTwo = $('#input-2');
        this.selection = $('.invalid-model-popover');
        this.inputOne.on('blur', function () {
            verifier.verify();
        });
        this.inputTwo.on('blur', function () {
            verifier.verify();
        });
        this.selection.on('change', function () {
            verifier.verify();
        });
    },

    verify: function () {
      var input1 = this.inputOne.val();
        var input2 = this.inputTwo.val();
        var select = verifier.selection.find("option:selected").text().trim();
        if (input1 && input2 && select !== "Select something") {
            this.createPopover();
        }
    },

    createPopover: function () {
       $(' .invalid-model-popover').popover({
            placement: 'top',
            html: true,
            content: "<div style='display:inline-block;width:100%'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right'>" +
                "</i></div>" +
                "<div style='font-weight:bold'>Note:</div>" +
                "<div> Choose something else</div>"
        }).click(function (event) {
            $(' .glyphicon-remove').click(function () {
                $(' .invalid-model-popover').popover('destroy');
            });
        
        });
        
        $(" .invalid-model-popover").popover('show');
        
        $('.invalid-model-popover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
  $(' .glyphicon-remove').click(function () {
                $(' .invalid-model-popover').popover('destroy');
            });
});
    }
}

verifier.init();
```

```css
#space {
    height: 300px;
}

.glyphicon-close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="space"></div>

<select data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" class="invalid-model-popover ">
    <option value="default" selected>Select something</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Optoin 3</option>
</select>
<input id="input-1" placeHolder='Search' type="text" autocomplete="off" />
<input id="input-2" placeHolder='Search' type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```